# Why is it that the enthalpy of hydration equals the difference of solvation enthalpies of anhydrous and hydrous salts

Tags: thermodynamics, enthalpy

Taking an example from my textbook

At finite dilution of CuSO4, heat is liberated
$$\ce{CuSO4(s) -> CuSO4 (aq)}.$$   ΔH of solvation = -15.8 kcal (anhydrous CuSO4 solvation reaction)

and when it is diluted further to infinity the enthalpy change is positive
$$\ce{CuSO4.5H2O(s) -> CuSO4.5H2O (aq)}.$$   ΔH of solvation = +2.9 kcal (CuSO4 pentahydrate solvation reaction)

**1**. Why is it that the enthalpy of hydration equals the difference of solvation enthalpies of anhydrous and hydrous salts.
ie

ΔH of hydration = ΔH of solvation of anhydrous salt - ΔH of solvation of hydrous salt.

**2**. Why does the anhydrous salt get hydrated only when there is excess solvent present? When water interacts with CuSO4 anhydrous should it not hydrate it before dissolving it?

[image: Textbook page:]

Comment: What textbook is it, and what is the exact wording of the question?

Comment: See e.g. https://www.lacitycollege.edu/Departments/Chemistry/documents/Chemistry-102-Experiments-Documents/E09ENTROPY page 3 and 4

Comment: I've added the paragraph from my textbook. Thank you.

Comment: Sorry. Your book is wrong ! $\ce{CuSO4·5H2O(aq)} $ does not exist. When dissolved in water, this substance is transformed into two ions :  $\ce{Cu^{2+}}$ and $\ce{SO4^{2}}$, which may be hydrated. But they are independent from one another. And $\ce{CuSO4·5H2O(aq)}$ does not exist in water

Comment: What do hydrated ions mean. Thank you

Comment: Be aware of terminology confusion, as hydration in context of ionic compound solutions usually means solvation by water, as hydration is special case of solvation. // Consider that enthalpy change over closed path ( real or formal) must be zero. So 1/salt hydrate loosing crystal water 2/dissolving anhydrous salt 3/ crystallization of salt hydrate has the total enthalpy change exactly zero.

Comment: A hydrated *salt*, like $\ce{CuSO4.5H2O(s)}$, is a *solid* ionic crystal that incorporates water into its interstices (i.e., into the spaces between the copper and sulfate ions).  If you heat it, this will tend to drive off the water (dehydrate it).  Such dehdrated compounds are hygroscopic, since they will then tend to absorb water back from the air.  By contrast, hydrated *ions*, like like $\ce{Cu^{2+}(aq)}$ and $\ce{SO4^{2-}(aq))}$, are ions dissolved in water.  They are called "hydrated" both because they are dissolved in water, and because the water forms a solvation shell around them.

Comment: @Maurice I didn't read the photo but that could be just a thermodynamic cycle, I suspect, and is perfectly OK doing it.